# What to do when op says send me the code?

Tags: discussion, questions

Many times I see a newbie directly asked for

1. send me the code if you have any solution for particular problem
2. send me your email I will send you the code

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884637/obtain-and-update-current-situation-in-google-map) is one of them.

Totally new way to asked help in SO for newbies. We really need one flag for that (e.g. Take a tour or How to ask?).

Comment: "Totally new way to asked help in SO" No, it's not new at all. You said yourself that you've seen this many times.

Comment: @BoltClock For new bies only. Every time i have seen a new biee asked this

Comment: I am not sure about what to do here... But i guess, you can send them logic to implement with their mistakes or wrong approach. If they are following right approach then there will not be an issue to raise the question. That's what i believe.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer yes but not every time. This is not a way to use SO.

Comment: How about asking for a fiddle?

Comment: @gizmore SO send this too.

Comment: In general, "plz send teh codez" questions are "too broad." Not sure that applies in the referenced case, that just looks like a run-of-the-mill bad question.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes i think `too broad` is right flag. because `unclear what you're asking` is failed in some situation like current.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to flag in my opinion, it's not really abusive or spam. (OP does not call you names or trying to sell you something.)

Just edit the bad parts out, and if nothing is left, downvote and flag as Very Low Quality, then it can be easily deleted from the VLQ review queue.

This is really not very different from any other "plz give me the codez" question, just in different form.

Comment: Does the `unclear what you're asking` flag fit to this?

Comment: @MD no, the point here isn't being unclear, it's the way the OP asks it.

Comment: why [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884637/obtain-and-update-current-situation-in-google-map) question is closed with that flagged then?

Comment: @MD dunno, not familiar with the contents there, but this is most  likely not related to the "please send me code" part of the question.